# Printing every rows of a data.table/data.frame

Tags: r, data.table

I use R 3.1.2 in terminal with Ubuntu 14.04, and data.table 1.9.4, and i'm not able to print every rows of a data.table or data.frame in this terminal. I can't understand why, and that's very frustrating...

```
library(data.table)
dtIris <- as.data.table(iris)
print(dtIris, nrow=150)
```

And i got this gap between row 76 and 105 in my result:
[image]

This gap is not necessarly between those exact rows, but there's always a gap.
But if i sink the results in a text file, every row appears...

The problem is the same if i directly print the `iris` data.frame..

Does someone has a clue? Is it my terminal, or R ?

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem in `data.table_1.9.5` using `R 3.1.3` and `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS`

Comment: You say it happens irrespective of data.frame or data.table.. This doesn't seem like an issue with data.table per se...

Comment: First, i thought it was related to data.table, but it's the same for a data.frame... Is it my terminal which behaves badly?